How can I save a CSV of points and array data from VTK data?
I am aiming to extract point and cell data in CSV form from a VTK file.
How can I generate a CSV that has coordinate and array data in one CSV? I am not certain if the cells in each CSV match each other.

If I save a CSV as Point Data, I get the coordinate data in CSV.
If I save a CSV file as cell data, I only get the array data in CSV.
If I save a CSV data as field data, I get a blank CSV.


CSV files tends to have the same semantic for each row (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), i.e. same columns.
Points and cells does not have the same semantic: you will not write same columns for each, so CSV is not relevant for your need. At least VTK will not support the use case you mention. You should find another file format, depending on:

the data structure you have
the software you want to use to read it back
(opt) the tools you can use to write it.

